# Remove space on file name before stored in databases

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

Can I remove a space on file name before it stored in database. I have tried with rename($oldname, $newname) but it doesn't work.

Here my php code

```
    $file_pathi = "image/";
    $file_path = $file_pathi . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        $query = 'insert into barang (nama, harga, kondisi, notelepon, foto) values ("'.$nama.'", "'.$harga.'", "'.$kondisi.'", "'.$notelepon.'", "http://192.168.43.226/jualan/barang_tes/'.$file_path.'")';
        mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `trim()`?

Comment: And the mysql_* functions shouldn't be used anymore, but that's nothing new and known for ages. Given the incredible skill of being able to read documentation, there is a huge statement on top as well that this is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), it will replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.

```
str_replace(" ","",$oldname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` function in php to replace space. Use the code below

```
$old_name="Hello World";
echo str_replace(" ","",$old_name); //Output HelloWorld
```

Hope this helps you